# Custom Hardware

Tags: android, kernel

I am in the process of redesigning my EE seniro design project (Digital Car Instrument Cluster) and would like to port the system from a custom light weight ubuntu to a android based system.  I was wondering can we install android onto a small atom based motherboard and if so does anyone know how we can writer driver to communicate with our usb datalogging hardware.

Comment: I would say it would be possible, they have compiled android for x86 processors. beyond that, i cant help. this would probably be better asked on http://superuser.com/ - maybe check out http://www.androidx86.org/

Answer (score 0):

Besides androidx86, you'll likely to need something like [ioio](http://codaset.com/ytai/ioio/wiki), which is to get adopted to android 2.3 as the reference hardware interface for Microcontrollers.